# where to start OpenID implementation in python,which API is better suits

Tags: python

im using python API in our research project.i read lot of ppt and material, and finally understand this concept now i have task to execute simple function which is chek user credential thorough openid provider and return successful after the valid user check.....

Comment: Can I just make a suggestion that you improve your spelling? It's quite irritating to read things wen u rite liek dis.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the recommendation of the Python OpenID library: their docs pages for the [server](http://openidenabled.com/files/python-openid/docs/2.2.4/openid.server.server-module.html) and [consumer](http://openidenabled.com/files/python-openid/docs/2.2.4/openid.consumer.consumer-module.html) modules both have useful Overview sections which you should read as a good starting point. The [examples directory](http://openidenabled.com/files/python-openid/repos/2.x.x/examples/) is also useful; I've written things starting from `server.py` and `consumer.py` from there.

Comment: thnks cmb,im trying to understand server.py and consumer,py programme.can u tell me more about this concept..

Comment: If you run either of those programs (as main, as in `python server.py`) you'll get an HTTP server which you can browse to (by default localhost:8000 for server, localhost:8001 for consumer). Then you can look at the behaviour of that demo and follow along in the code to see how it works. If that doesn't help, try asking a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [Python OpenID](http://openidenabled.com/python-openid/) library?

Comment: yes...i know but im new in this language.give me idea that how i should start this implementation

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish, I can only recommend a Google sourcecode search:

http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=openid&btnG=Search+Code&hl=en&as_lang=python&as_license_restrict=i&as_license=&as_package=&as_filename=&as_case=

Comment: no,i understand  concept of openid but i have confused where should i start first module to implement these function......